# How to Check Facebook invite app to friends is successfully sent invitation or not sent in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-invite

I have Sent invitation to friend successfully ,but i want to check is sent or not Successfully. after call sent invitation successfully i want to send data to API. please anyone help me how to check invite friend successfully or not . Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think  onActivityResults will help you,Please post some code so we can understand

Comment: thanks for comment